# Select characters like ù

Tags: mysql, unicode, collation

There is a table with 2 records - `u` and `ù`:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (`text` text NOT NULL) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `tbl` (`text`) VALUES ('u'), ('ù');
```

I want to select row with ù:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `text` = 'ù';
```

The result is

```
+------+
| text |
+------+
| u    |
| ù    |
+------+
```

What is the problem here? How can I work with such characters?

Comment: I can't replicate that result using MySQL 5.1.72 on Linux. I only get back the `ù` record. Literally copied and pasted what you have in your question.

Comment: That is strange, I have this result on Windows7 and Ubuntu12

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: When using your `CREATE TABLE` above, I still get the `latin1` charset, not `utf8` which may explain why our results differ. In any case, I think chooban's pointed you the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to do with the collation used when mysql compares values. If you run the following query, you'll see which collation is in effect:

```
show collation where Charset = 'utf8';
```

One of those should have a `Default` value of `yes`. In my case it's `utf8_general_ci`. This collation uses Unicode ordering to equate characters with accents and those without.

If you run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `text` = 'ù' collate utf8_bin;
```

Then you'll only get one row back. There's a lot more information in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-general.html).